# Origin of "Every dollar you spend is a political act"?

Tags: expressions, quotes, origin-unknown

Who was the first to say this?

> Every dollar you spend is a political act.

I find it here and there and it seems like a quote, but I can't find the origin.

Comment: Seems like the origin, but i mostly see the shortend (?) version.

Comment: Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quote close to the one you are suggesting is:

> - “Every dollar you spend . . . or don't spend . . . is a vote you cast for the world you want.”
>
>   - By L.N. Smith in his book  *Sunrise over Disney* (2011)

There also a similar [quote](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100112111511AAUU7sV) by the writer  Anne Lappe' which seems to predate  the above one:

> - “Every time you spend money, you're casting a vote for the kind of world you want.”